# public procedure not visible in Delphi XE8

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have a secondary form for logging in my application, for which I have a procedure `AddLine`:

```
type
  TFormLog = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
    procedure AddLine(aString: String);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormLog: TFormLog;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TFormLog }

procedure TFormLog.AddLine(aString: String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(aString);
end;
```

When I use autocomplete (Ctrl-Shift_C) Delphi adds the `AddLine` procedure to the `private` section, so obviously the procedure is invisible to the main form when I try

```
FormLog.AddLine('some text');
```

But **moving the declaration to the public section** doesn't help:

```
type
  TFormLog = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure AddLine(aString: String);
  end;
```

I still get a compiler error that the `AddLine` procedure is unresolved. I did add the log unit to the `uses` clause, so `Formlog` is known in the main form.
Trying to access the TMemo directly has the same effect.

How can I fix my code such that I can add text to the log form from my main form?

Comment: Move `AddLine` to the public section and save the form. Add the unit to your project. If this does not work, the compiler must be picking up another unit with the same name or using an earlier compiled unit (not seeing the source somehow).

Comment: As for picking up another unit, I would start procmon, start compiling, stop procmon and verify what .pas files get compiled. Most likely, it's not the one you assume.

Comment: Report your actual error and show the actual problematic code, not the code that does work.   The code that is correct is irrelevant.  Use copy and paste to report compiler errors not "it doesn't work" or "I get a compiler error".

Answer (score 1):

Public members are visible from code in other units. Possible explanations for your error include:

1. The method is not public.
2. Your instance variable is not of the type that you think it is.
3. You aren't compiling the code that you think you are compiling, or the linker is finding code that you do not intend it to find.

You also say:

> Trying to access the `TMemo` directly has the same effect.

Again, since that has published visibility, it is visible from outside the unit. Clearly something akin to items 2 or 3 above is what is going on.

The bottom line is that public (and published) members can be seen from any code. The problem is in your code (which only you can see) and you should try to solve this by asking questions of that code rather than worrying that the compiler is defective.

On a broader level, the code presented in the question declares the method as `private`. Clearly that member is not visible from outside the unit. As a general rule, you should present the code about which you are requesting help.

Furthermore, if you are asking about a compiler error, report the error verbatim. Describing your understanding of the error is a rich source for confusion. It's quite common for people to misunderstand compiler errors. If they then describe their misunderstanding, communication breaks down. Report the compiler error verbatim and then there is zero scope for misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks David. Where did I say anything about the compiler being defective? Nowhere, I should say. Also, the code I show is what Delphi made of it (putting the declaration in the private section). I said I moved it to `public`.

Comment: It's always best to show the code that you wish us to comment on. For all we know, you didn't succeed in moving the code to the public section. It seems to me that you think that you have a public member that is not visible. If you think that is the case, then it would be a compiler defect.

Answer (score -1):

i believe that AddLine is Private in some place in VCL Delphi.

thus try CHANGE the procedure/method name
example  one  name totally diferent as your name hehehe and see the error occur test the access to the variables or objects into your proc/method

or create one new project for test

note: if ADDLINE is one method of MEMO so the compiler cannot resolve what called will be done (i believe that is it)